# Editar archivo de texto con Batch

Tags: windows, batch, windows-server-2012, línea-de-comandos, msdos

tengo la siguiente situacion, debo monitorear inicios de sesion en un TS 
Necesito crear un log con un batch, la idea es que genere un archivo te texto en la primera ejecucion y luego añadir lineas de texto en el archivo cada vez que el bat corre (lo pondre como GPO al iniciar sesion de usuario)

tengo el codigo que genera el log con fecha hora y usuario, pero no puedo hacer que me vaya agregando mas lineas en el log

`echo %time% %username% > c:\registro.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si haces

```
echo %time% %username% > "c:\registro.txt"
```

Sobreescribes el archivo, para añadir líneas de texto debes utilizar `>>`

```
echo %time% %username% >> "c:\registro.txt"
```